# Microsoft SignTool - is there any network mechanism behind it?

Tags: powershell, signtool

I am performing code signing using Microsoft SignTool inside a CI/CD pipeline.
I have a bunch of files to sign (over 15) and I am performing it inside a Powershell for loop.

To give more background, certificates which are used are received from a 3party tool, which puts them inside local certificate store.

The main issue is that in some cases my Powershell for loop is being interrupted by SignTool which screams
`"SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria."`.
The nature of the issue seems to be very random - it happens on different files on the loop, sometimes it doesn't fail at all.

To ensure - certificates are in place (I have an additional step for checking, if the given certificate is in the store), but SignTool seems not to see it anyway.

I am wondering, if there is any kind of network mechanism, which forces SignTool to perform checking for the certificate with the code signing server?

Comment: Short answer: **yes** (eg, when accessing a certificate timestamping service, checking CRL/OCSP during verification, if your key storage is over a network provider, etc).  Can you provide an example of your `signtool.exe` command-line for a better answer?